# Get properties of SharePoint in powershell as non-admin?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, csom

My ultimate goal is to pull data from a SharePoint doc and update a PowerPoint doc automatically.

I'm testing if I can get simple information.

However, it appears that I cannot even read a sharepoint directory.

- I have access to the internal web sharepoint, as a user, when logged on.
- I have access to my sharepoint directory
- I do not have admin on my laptop nor any access to the sharepoint server itself.

I have tried this:

```
$site=Get-SPsite "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/mydirectory"
$web=$site.OpenWeb()
$properties=$web.Properties
```

I'm getting errors like:

```
Get-SPsite : The term 'Get-SPsite' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
```

Question:  Can I do this without admin privs?

Answer (score 1):

No, to run powershell against the SharePoint farm you need "SharePoint_Shell_Access" permission in the farm.

you cant run the powershell from your local machine against the SharePoint farm, you need to enable the remoteing which required admin level permission.

in your requirement, best bet is using client scripting i.e. csom, json etc. Check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057074/how-to-download-upload-files-from-to-sharepoint-2013-using-csom

Comment: Thanks.  Quick google and it looks like I would need Visual Studio or the like and they are not going to approve that for me.  I'm trying to automate a tedious task I was assigned.

Comment: you need to create client side scripting as no one will allow to directly run powershell on the servers.